# Accounting for uncertainty in a mixed-effects regression

Tags: standard-error, uncertainty, weights

I have calculated an effect size along a dataset of experiments distributed worldwide through a mixed-effects meta-regression. The effect size in the dataset depends on climate (y ~ temperature + precipitation):

`meta <- metafor::rma(es, var, data=df, mods= ~ 1 + precip + temp))`

As I have data for temperature and precipitation for virtually all points on Earth, I have upscaled this effect and standard error (SE) globally, that is, applying the model to predict the effect for all points on Earth, thus creating a gridded map:

```
pred <- predict(meta, newmods = cbind(s.df$precipitation, s.df$temperature))
```

This upscaled map of SE thus represent the meta-analysis derived uncertainty. What this SE does not reflect is the uncertainty derived from the fact that the number of experiments in the dataset used to run the meta-regression is obviously limited, yet I predict the effect globally, even in areas not covered by experiments. In particular, it is very obvious in the dataset that tropical ecosystems are not well represented, with just a couple of experiments in the dataset. Therefore, the upscaled effect should be more uncertain in tropical regions, but in the current version, SE is not particularly higher in the tropics than in other areas, because the model just depends on climate, not ecosystem representativeness. I would like to add a further level of uncertainty to SE based on the number of studies per type of ecosystem in the dataset. The idea is that ecosystems that are poorly sampled should have a higher SE than ecosystems with plenty of measurements in the dataset.

Ecosystem type does not appear to explain variation in the effect, but this could just be the consequence of the low sample size of some ecosystem types. Regardless, ecosystem type should be forced to be included in the model somehow so that poorly sampled ecosystems show larger uncertainty. How can I do this? Should I include ecosystem type as a random effect?

Comment: At the moment this question is a bit unclear.  You have a "gridded dataset" of estimated SE values of an effect.  What are the variables that define the grid?  Is it a grid of the different ecosystems, or is it something else?  Did the number of observations in each ecosystem form a part of the initial estimation of the SE values for the effect, or are they new information that is independent of this?

Comment: I hope is clearer now

Comment: What variable is the SE measurement for?  What kind of model was this?  Some kind of regression-type model?

Comment: Just to help you clarify this question, the answer will depend a great deal on what you have already done when fitting the model.  Most models will automatically take account of the number of data points you put into them without requiring any special weighting.  If you are adding exogenous information on the number of data points, that will usually be added in within the model by a weighting parameter.  So if you can give a better idea of what you've already done, them I'm sure people on here can help you a lot better.

Comment: Hi Ben, the current model does not reflect the type of spatial uncertainty related to the representation of ecosystem types. I have updated my Q including more background. Thanks for your ideas for a clearer Q

Comment: I don't think weighting is the answer. You may want to add a variable into your model that classifies your regions by ecosystem. Then run a random effects meta-analysis model. The variance terms that you include in your effects should incorporate the uncertainty present in each sample. By adding a ecosystem 'category' variable to your model you should be able to get out separate estimates by type. If, as you say, the tropical category has fewer measurements, you should see larger model-based standard errors for the estimates pertaining to that region.

Comment: Would you add 'Biome' as a moderator or as a random effect? i.e.: mod1 <- rma.mv(es, var, data=df, random= ~1|Biome, mods= ~ 1 + MAP + MAT) or mod2 <- rma.mv(es, var, data=df, mods= ~ 1 + MAP + MAT + Biome)?

Comment: @MattBarstead please help

Comment: `metafor::rma` is a *specific* function in R. Could you more *generally* explain your model and how you currently calculate SE?

Comment: What I currently understand is that you model something based on temperature and precipitation levels, but that you would also like to use, in addition, the ecosystem. Is that right? In particular you do not want the model predictions to be influenced by ecosystem, but only the standard error of the predictions?

Comment: When I upscale the effect globally, I am projecting the effect to areas (ecosystems) in which we don't really know the behaviour of the system because no measurements have been taken there. Therefore, a quantification of uncertainties has to be accompanied with the upscaled effect, with areas (ecosystems) not sampled showing large uncertainties.

Comment: I do not really get the term 'upscale the effect', as well as how and where 'ecosystem' is placed in your model. I see that you used 'temp' and 'precip' in your model. Where does 'ecosystem' suddenly come from (what is it, how do you measure it, etc)? And why did you not place 'ecoystem' in your model when it is supposed to have a moderating effect?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings that's exactly the point of my question, I don't know how to include "ecosystem" in the model in order to account for the uncertainties associated with the low sample size in some types of ecosystems. Upscaling means simply predicting the effect globally even though the model was developed using data for just a few locations. To do so, we need globally available data for the predictors of the model. Therefore, when upscaling, there is uncertainty associated with the fact that you don't know the behaviour of the system in some regions (in this case, ecosystems).

Comment: This is not a statistical question: "I don't know how to include "ecosystem" in the model". You can build your statistical model based on the idea that your measured '$y$' is a linear function of 'precipitation' and 'temperature'. However to make any conclusions on the statistics based on an 'unknown' effect of ecosystem, *without assumptions about the influence/role of ecosystem in the model* makes no sense. You have to specify these assumptions before making any argument (/calculation) about the statistics.

Comment: You have to specify the role of ecosystem. Prior expectations matter. Even when you are doing a frequentist analysis (in that case the priors are just called assumptions). Compare for instance with the role of some other, likely unimportant, variable. Say, whether the country for which the prediction is made has a 'z' in it's name. If you do not specify the way in which the ecosystem can/cannot have an effect, then you can not extrapolate/scale the predictions while taking the role of the ecosystem into account.

Comment: MartijnWeterings I am really explaining things as clear as I am able to given my current skills, but your replies seem to just focus on criticising the way I word my question rather than trying to help. Even when the question was less clear, @MattBarstead found the key to try to help me and refocus the whole thing. I will wait and see if he can give me more clues now that I have advanced a little

Answer (score 1):

If you add ecosystem as a main/interaction random effect then the model will indeed incorporate additional parameters for the variability of the dependent variable as function of ecosystems. This allows you to incorporate additional modes of uncertainty for predictions. This will be based on:

- **different predicted $\hat{y}$** Since you assume that ecosystems can have an effect, the model will also, likely, make the effects different. (But as you say this does not appear to be so much the case and your fit will give little significant effects. This is no problem) If you make some manual custom made model then you can have the effect size the same and just the error of the estimates vary as function of the ecosystem (heteroskedasticity, which is easy if you apply fixed weights for different ecosystems and a bit more difficult if the weights are unknown)
- and also **different standard error for $\hat{y}$**, because the means, or $E(\hat{y})$, are being estimated with variations of sample size.

Answer (score 0):

To address this comment explicitly as an extension of your original question:

> Would you add 'Biome' as a moderator or as a random effect? i.e.: mod1
>   <- rma.mv(es, var, data=df, random= ~1|Biome, mods= ~ 1 + MAP + MAT)
>   or mod2 <- rma.mv(es, var, data=df, mods= ~ 1 + MAP + MAT + Biome)?

My instinct would be to incorporate biome as a moderator (i.e., as a predictor of your random effects). Using the `predict` function and feeding your model the relevant data (which would now include three variables), and specifying the `levels=` argument, you should get a series of estimates and intervals (specified to your level of uncertainty). For biomes that contain more variability in their effect sizes (either as a function of small samples or as a result of greater variation overall) you should see wider intervals. Those intervals can be incorporated into simple tables or even included in graphics, depending on your final goals.

Comment: The standard error is often related to a *single* estimate of variance $\hat{\sigma}$ multiplied with additional terms including the independent variables. If the regression and determination of the SE is carried out according to this standard format (ie. assuming homogeneous variance), then there will be no influence of the 'greater variation overall' in a certain ecosystem, and only the sample size has an effect on the error estimate of the predictions.

Comment: I agree to a degree but it depends on how the data are structured/collected. In a world in which there are multiple distinct effect sizes for each biome, each with their own unique sample (say a set of measurements from the Amazon, from a jungle in sub-Saharan Africa, and from a rainforest in Indonesia), the variability in those point estimates as well as the variability in their variance terms (i.e., the SEs of each effect from each sample) would contribute to the model-based SE for that biome no?

Comment: You can estimate a point estimate SE in several different ways, but the standard is, I believe, assuming a *single*, $\hat\sigma$, estimate of the deviation. This means that a *multiple/hereogeneous* deviation is not taken into account. Still, variations of the SE occur because the estimates of fit curves and predictions do not only depend $\hat\sigma$ but also on the number in the sample (where the fits/means improve if you have larger samples, but predictions will always be susceptible to the error term $\sigma$ ).

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I seem to understand both of you suggest adding ecosystem type ("Biome") as a moderator, which should produce large SE values in biomes with lower sample size. Great. What I don't understand is why you both seem to disagree in some aspects. What are the differences you are discussing? I will start a bounty again so you can have the extra reputation you deserve for helping me out.

Comment: From a technical point, I can't still manage to make the predict function work. "Biome" is categorical, with > levels(df$Biome)
[1] "Boreal_Forest"    "Cropland"         "Grassland"        "Shrubland"       
[5] "Temperate_Forest" "Tropical_Forest"

Comment: pred.mv <- predict(meta.mv, 
+                       newmods = cbind(s.df$precipitation, s.df$temperature, s.df$Biome))
Error in predict.rma. Dimensions of 'newmods' do not match dimensions of the model.

Comment: I am assuming for your second question that your object meta.mv was run with the categorical variable included? If not that would be something that needs to happen first. If so I wonder how metafor handles categorical variables. You may have to dummy code them manually but I don't know off the top of my head. Would need to check into the documentation. Those are my first two quick takes for the practical side of things. I haven't had a chance to respond more thoroughly to the conceptual side of things just yet and will try to do so some time this week.